# Play Youtube video in Flex app and stream it live

Tags: flash, youtube, flex4, video-streaming

Is it possible to play a Youtube video inside a Flex 4 application and at the same time publish it to a Flash server as a live stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no problems with playing Youtube video (of course it's streaming protocol is rtmp), but as far as I know you can't attach incoming stream's video to outgoing one, because attachVideo/attachAudio methods can use only Camera/Microphone as input. If you want to restream something to your server, you can use FFmpeg, it's really easy!

Comment: Basically I want the restreaming process take place in a web application (Flex) and as far as I am concerned FFmpeg is a desktop application. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can use java FFmpeg wrapper (for example Xuggler which can both play and stream RTSP/RTMP in newest codecs), so you cam make an applet and embed it into a webpage. Do notice, that the aplet, however, is worse than desktop app, becourse it uses much more resourses and it's size is bigger.